# Mountain Lion Postgres could not connect

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, osx-mountain-lion

After my update to mountain lion my postgres doest work. It is still running but my applications cant connect to it anymore.

```
$ ps aux | grep postgres
postgres         204   0.0  0.0  2446960    836   ??  Ss    7:31AM   0:00.59 postgres: stats collector process    
postgres         203   0.0  0.1  2478732   2240   ??  Ss    7:31AM   0:00.41 postgres: autovacuum launcher process    
postgres         202   0.0  0.0  2478600    584   ??  Ss    7:31AM   0:00.34 postgres: wal writer process    
postgres         201   0.0  0.0  2478600    784   ??  Ss    7:31AM   0:00.48 postgres: writer process    
postgres          95   0.0  0.0  2446960    368   ??  Ss    7:31AM   0:00.11 postgres: logger process    
postgres          64   0.0  0.2  2478600   7972   ??  Ss    7:31AM   0:00.26 /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/postmaster -D/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data
anezio         10205   0.0  0.0  2432768    624 s000  R+    8:01AM   0:00.00 grep postgres
```

and my applications are returning this error:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I still can connect to psql with the command /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/psql -U postgres

Seems like something is not pointing to the right place

Comment: sounds like you have some other build of postgres on that machine that you're using psql from. maybe you could tell us about your installation history too?

Comment: Ive installed it using the one click installer from postgresql.com. It was working fine before my update do mountain lion

Comment: Ive solved this problem uninstalling and reinstalling Postgresql. Thanks

Comment: This solved it for me:  http://jaygoldman.com/2012/11/fixing-postgres-connection-errors-on-mountain-lion/  (summary: make a symbolic link from the actual location of the socket file to where pg is looking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem by uninstalling and re-installing it

Answer (score 8):

I just had the same problem. Personally I just reinstalled from the Postgres installer (postgresql-9.1.3-1-osx.dmg in my case), rebooted my mac and all is fine again. p.s. re-installing didn't zap my databases :)

Answer (score 5):

Check which `psql` you're using. I had the same problem while using the [Postgres.app](http://postgresapp.com/) server from Heroku and found that I was using Apple's `/usr/bin/psql` client based on my `$PATH` setting. Either set your `$PATH` to use your Postgres library or use the full path to your installed `psql`.

Comment: I have postgres installed at the brew location /usr/local/bin. I had changed my /etc/paths to put /usr/local/bin at the top of the search paths so that brew installs were found first (before /usr/bin installs). The upgrade to Mountain Lion reset the contents of /etc/paths; consequently I too started to pick up the apple-installed psql in /usr/bin (and the nasty message "could not connect to server ...") after the upgrade. Putting /usr/local/bin back to the top of /etc/paths fixed everything.

Answer (score 2):

The default Unix domain socket path is hardcoded in libpq.
What may have happen is that before the upgrade, your application used the libpq library installed by the Postgres one-click installer, while after the upgrade a different version of this library gets picked up.

To work around the problem, from a programmer's point of view, you could specify the socket directory instead of relying on the default.
To locate the correct directory if you don't know it already, connect to any database as a superuser (generally postgres) and issue in SQL:

```
SHOW unix_socket_directory;
```

Then change or reconfigure your app with the path obtained in the host field of the connect call (e.g. in a connect string: `host=/path/to/socket dbname=d user=u`). Libpq will recognize it as a unix socket directory because it starts with a slash, as opposed to a hostname or IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I totally forgot that this socket file will be hidden because of the dot. Make sure you use `ls -A /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432` if you are checking to see if the socket is actually there.

My postgres app started accepting a connection again from psql after I did the following. I think it had something to do with step 3.

1. Exit the postgres app.
2. In terminal type `postgres -D ~/Library/Application\ Support/Postgres/var`. This is the data directory if you are using the postgres app. If you are not using the postgres app you need to find out what the data directory really is.
3. I got a prompt from OS X asking if I want to allow incoming traffic. I clicked yes.
4. In a different terminal tab type `psql`. You should connect successfully.
5. Type `\q` to exit psql.
6. Back on the tab running postgres, type `ctrl c` to stop postgres.
7. Start the postgres app. psql should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mountain lion comes with it's own psql client (/usr/bin/psql) which apparently tries to connect postgres by searching the local socket file in a different location than the one from your installer. You could either change your PATH variable to include first your postgres bin folder or replace the default /usr/bin/psql with the one on your installation.